# Show sqlite database records using cursor

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am not able to show records of SQLite table

my MySQLiteHelper class

```
public Cursor showImageRecords()
{
    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_Name, new String[]{COLUMN1, COLUMN2}, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

I am calling selection query as

```
public void showImages()
{
    MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(context, null, null, 1);
    mySQLiteHelper.openDatabase();    
    Cursor cursor=mySQLiteHelper.showImageRecords();

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        imagePath=cursor.getString(1);
        imageDate=cursor.getString(2);

        txtDetails.setText(imagePath+ "  " + imageDate +"\n");
    }
    cursor.close();
    mySQLiteHelper.closeDatabase();
}
```

logcat shows

```
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5351)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1001)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4189)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10507)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10456)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6517)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3729)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3587)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3562)
06-04 16:05:33.402: E/AndroidRuntime(4954):     at
```

any advice and suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper=new MySQLiteHelper(context, null, null, 1);
```

to

```
MySQLiteHelper mySQLiteHelper=new MySQLiteHelper();
```

also displaying log cat error would be good

check this [tutorial](http://android4beginners.com/2013/06/lesson-1-3-how-to-modify-textview-in-java-code-findviewbyid-settext-and-gettext-methods/)

Comment: i changed my constructor like u suggest , and posted my logcat details

Comment: @Shruti yuor problem is in this code ..        txtDetails.setText(imagePath+ "  " + imageDate +"\n");
you only can set text

Comment: yes ,i ll try to debug my code , value in string variable is coming bug error is in txtDetails.setText(imagePath+ "  " + imageDate +"\n"); Line , so how can i set text in textview

Comment: @Shruti imagePath seems its a test view , you cannot do that

Comment: means i cannot set special characters like / in text view??

Comment: @Shruti I added in the question a tutorial explains how to work with text view, if you still have any question feel free to ask. if the tutorial was helpful accept my answer